# What tor product would you recomend to anony,mously post a cl ad to prevent immediate flagging?

Tags: anonymity

What tor product can I use to make a cl listing and not expose my ip for flagging? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tor Browser on a computer. Use the Orbot mobil app on an Android device: https://www.torproject.org/

Tor Support Portal — FAQs — Which platforms is Tor Browser available for?: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/teams/CommunityTeam/Support#WhichplatformsisTorBrowseravailablefor